# Get ticker id to follow price

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to plot the percentage change across multiple assets. I want to get the ticker id to show with the percentage change.  The problem is trying to match the ID with the change, and having the id move with the corresponding change.  This is what I have

```
study("My Script", precision=2)

btc = security('ftx:btcperp', timeframe.period, close)
eth = security('ftx:ethperp', timeframe.period, close)
ltc = security('ftx:ltcperp', timeframe.period, close)
doge = security('ftx:dogeperp', timeframe.period, close)

a = (btc - btc[1]) / btc[1] * 100
b = (eth - eth[1]) / eth[1] * 100
c = (ltc - ltc[1]) / ltc[1] * 100
d = (doge - doge[1]) / doge[1] * 100

nsec0(v1,v2,v3,v4) =>
    v = array.new_float()
    array.push(v,v1),array.push(v,v2),array.push(v,v3),array.push(v,v4)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    array.get(v,3)
nsec1(v1,v2,v3,v4) =>
    v = array.new_float()
    array.push(v,v1),array.push(v,v2),array.push(v,v3),array.push(v,v4)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    array.get(v,2)
nsec2(v1,v2,v3,v4) =>
    v = array.new_float()
    array.push(v,v1),array.push(v,v2),array.push(v,v3),array.push(v,v4)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    array.get(v,1)
nsec3(v1,v2,v3,v4) =>
    v = array.new_float()
    array.push(v,v1),array.push(v,v2),array.push(v,v3),array.push(v,v4)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    array.get(v,0)

plot(nsec0(a,b,c,d),style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.blue, offset=0)
plot(nsec1(a,b,c,d),style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.white, offset=-1)
plot(nsec2(a,b,c,d),style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.yellow, offset=-2)
plot(nsec3(a,b,c,d),style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.orange, offset=-3)

lt = tostring(nsec0(a,b,c,d), '#.##')
ln = label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text=lt, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white)
label.delete(ln[1])

lt1 = tostring(nsec1(a,b,c,d), '#.##')
ln1 = label.new(x = bar_index - 1, y = na, text=lt1, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white)
label.delete(ln1[1])

lt2 = tostring(nsec2(a,b,c,d), '#.##')
ln2 = label.new(x = bar_index - 2, y = na, text=lt2, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white)
label.delete(ln2[1])

lt3 = tostring(nsec3(a,b,c,d), '#.##')
ln3 = label.new(x = bar_index - 3, y = na, text=lt3, yloc=yloc.price, color=color.white)
label.delete(ln3[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", precision=2)

var label[] labels  = array.new_label()
var float[] v       = array.new_float(4,na)

f_label_move(_i) =>
    lbl = array.get(labels,_i)
    label.set_text(lbl, tostring(array.get(v,_i), '#.##') + '%')
    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index - _i, array.max(v))

f_get_data(_sec) => security(_sec, timeframe.period, close)

f_change(_src) => change(_src)  / _src[1]  * 100

btc  = f_get_data('ftx:btcperp')
eth  = f_get_data('ftx:ethperp')
ltc  = f_get_data('ftx:ltcperp')
doge = f_get_data('ftx:dogeperp')

a = f_change(btc)
b = f_change(eth)
c = f_change(ltc)
d = f_change(doge)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 3
        array.push(labels, label.new(na, na, "", color=color.white))

if barstate.islast
    v := array.from(a,b,c,d)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    
    for i = 0 to 3
        f_label_move(i)

plot(array.get(v,0), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.blue,   offset= 0)
plot(array.get(v,1), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.white,  offset=-1)
plot(array.get(v,2), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.yellow, offset=-2)
plot(array.get(v,3), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.orange, offset=-3)
```

Edit 1 - This shows the names of the securities.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", precision=2)

var string[]    label_names     = array.new_string(4,na)
var label[]     label_values    = array.new_label()
var float[]     v               = array.new_float(4,na)

f_label_move(_i) =>
    lbl = array.get(label_values,_i)
    label.set_text(lbl, array.get(label_names,_i) + '\n' + tostring(array.get(v,_i), '#.##') + '%')
    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index - _i, array.max(v))

f_get_data(_sec) => security(_sec, timeframe.period, close)

f_change(_src) => change(_src)  / _src[1]  * 100

btc  = f_get_data('ftx:btcperp')
eth  = f_get_data('ftx:ethperp')
ltc  = f_get_data('ftx:ltcperp')
doge = f_get_data('ftx:dogeperp')

a = f_change(btc)
b = f_change(eth)
c = f_change(ltc)
d = f_change(doge)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 3
        array.push(label_values, label.new(na, na, "", color=color.white))

if barstate.islast
    v := array.from(a,b,c,d)
    labels_orig = array.from("btc","eth","ltc","doge")
    v_orig      = array.copy(v)
    array.sort(v, order.descending)
    for i = 0 to 3
        idx = array.indexof(v_orig, array.get(v,i))
        array.set(label_names, i, array.get(labels_orig, idx))
    
    for i = 0 to 3
        f_label_move(i)

plot(array.get(v,0), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.blue,   offset= 0)
plot(array.get(v,1), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.white,  offset=-1)
plot(array.get(v,2), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.yellow, offset=-2)
plot(array.get(v,3), style=plot.style_columns, show_last=1, color=color.orange, offset=-3)
```

Comment: Not quite.  The ticker id still isn't showing.  This is how it shows up 

https://www.tradingview.com/x/2puMGXEL/

I'd like it to look like this

https://www.tradingview.com/x/dEQwj1UH/

Comment: Added Edit 1 - This shows the names of the securities.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!